# Swift - Interactive dismissing form sheet doesn't work iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I'm presenting my `UIViewController` with `modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet`. Everything works as expected except interactive dismissing this controller (I drag form sheet from the top down). Controller is dismissed but it's `presentingViewController` doesn't move back. It remains stucked with black edges around.

If I dismiss presented controller using `dismiss(animated:completion:)`, `presentingViewController` moves back as expected so it seems it doesn't work just when user dismiss it by dragging.

If you need any other details let me know. Thank you.

I'm using iOS 13.3 and Xcode 11.2.1.

[image]

---

**Update:**

I found a problem.  This view which I presented contained `UITableView`. I was using my method to set its `tableFooterView`:

```
extension UITableView {
    func setFooterView(_ view: UIView) {
        view.frame = bounds

        view.setNeedsLayout()
        view.layoutIfNeeded()

        let height = view.systemLayoutSizeFitting(
        CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: UIView.layoutFittingCompressedSize.height)
        ).height
        var frame = view.frame
        frame.size.height = height
        view.frame = frame

        tableFooterView = view

        sectionFooterHeight = 0
    }
}
```

...and I called this method in my view controller in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` since I thought that this is where I should set this footer view *(Simply because we were using it like this in various projects ‍♂️):*

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    tableView.setFooterView(footerView)
}
```

But I wasn't right. Simply calling it in `viewDidLoad()` resolved it.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.setFooterView(footerView)
}
```

No the question is: **why?**

If anyone could provide correct explanation why this happens I would be grateful and I would reward him/her with bounty.

Comment: did you get solution Robert?

Comment: i'm working in xcode 11.3 and  self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) work's for me.

Comment: @Harish still nothing :/

Comment: @VipinPareek yes, programmatically it can be dismissed without problems, but question is not about this. Question is about dismissing using default "drag gesture".

Comment: I did this in Storyboard with just simple two controllers and all works fine. Xcode 11.2 / iOS 13.2

Comment: @Asperi I know. For me it works in other projects. But here with my specific hierarchy it doesn’t work and I need to know why and how to fix it ‍♂️

Comment: How do you imagine help for you if there Is no code? Would you provide link to project? Or some working issue demo?

Comment: @Asperi check update. Sorry for my bad description of problem. I was confused and I wasn't able to create "working" demo since I didn't know what could cause this problem. Anyway I found a problem and now I would appreciate if anyone could tell me what is going on 

Comment: Do NOT call `view.layoutIfNeeded()`. It will be called in due time.

Comment: @bshirley oh, I see. I guess this is the problem, during interactive dismissing `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` is called many times and calling `view.layoutIfNeeded()` breaks it. Hmm, could you elaborate you answer below? :)

Comment: `setNeedsLayout()` will cause things to be re-laid out. If you're not implementing `layoutSubviews()` then none of those calls makes a difference. The `layoutIfNeeded()` will immediately invoke the `layoutSubviews()` which there's typically no need for. (I have no idea why these are interacting with a dismiss)